# Angularfire tutorial on thinkster io login status not updated

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I am following the AngularFire tutorial on [thinkster](https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/learn-to-build-realtime-webapps/). The `$simpleLogin` service has been deprecate, so I changed some of the code.

The factory:

```
app.factory('Auth', function ($firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope, $location){
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var Auth = { 
    register = function(){
        //...
    },
    resolveUser = function(){
        //...
    },
    signedIn = function(){
        var authData = ref.getAuth();
        if (authData) {
            console.log("User is signed in");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("User is not signed in");                
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The controller:

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Post', 'Auth', function ($scope, $location, Post, Auth){
    $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

    $scope.submitPost = function (){
        Post.create($scope.post).then(function (ref){
            $location.path('/posts/' + ref.name());
            $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};
        })
    };

    $scope.signedIn = Auth.signedIn();
    $scope.logout = Auth.logout;
}]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
  })
  .when('/posts/:postId', {
    templateUrl: 'views/showpost.html',
    controller: 'PostViewCtrl'
  })
  .when('/register', {
    templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
    controller: 'AuthCtrl',
    resolve: {
        user: function(Auth){
            return Auth.signedIn();
        }
    }
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'AuthCtrl',
    resolve: {
        signedIn: function(Auth){
            return Auth.signedIn();
        }
    }
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

Relevant part of the template:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li ng-show="signedIn">
    <a ng-href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>       
  </li>
  <li ng-hide="signedIn">
    <a href="#/register">Register</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-hide="signedIn">
    <a href="#/login">Login</a>
  </li>
```

The problem is the `signedIn` variable doesn't get updated when I login in, so the register and Login links are still visible to the user while the logout link is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure out a solution,

In the controller:

```
  $scope.auth = Auth.auth();
  $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.user = authData;
    });
  });
```

In the factory:

```
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
  var Auth = {
        auth: function(){
            return auth;
        }
      }

  Return Auth;
```

So I think it's the `$timeout` that makes the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You controller sets `signedIn` as follows:

```
$scope.signedIn = Auth.signedIn();
```

When the controller is initialized, this code executes and the scope variable is set **only once**.

If you look in the [Firebase documentation for monitoring authentication state](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html), you will find this example just above the one you seem to have started with:

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    // user authenticated with Firebase
    console.log("User ID: " + authData.uid + ", Provider: " + authData.provider);
  } else {
    // user is logged out
  }
});
```

Where your snippet checks (using `getAuth`) whether the user is currently logged in, this monitors the referenced Firebase (using `onAuth`) until a user logs in. At that point you can set/update your property in the scope and notify AngularJS of the change:

```
$scope.signedIn = !!ref.getAuth(); // true if the user is already logged in
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
    $scope.signedIn = !!ref.getAuth(); 
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

In case you are already using AngularFire, you can simply use the `$firebaseAuth` service that comes with it and accomplish the same: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication

Comment: thanks for the help, not sure how to implement it exactly (i'm a beginner), but enough to set me on the right track. I finally found that using $timeout with $onAuth can produce the result I want.